Are readiness probes and liveness probes independent of each other?
I am having a hard time to understand the behaviour of readiness probes and liveness probes. And need some input to rightfully set them:
Here's my initial configuration:
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /readiness
              port: 4001
            initialDelaySeconds: 300
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /liveness
              port: 4001
            initialDelaySeconds: 300
            periodSeconds: 30

Based on my understanding after reading documentation and blogs, as soon as the pod starts up, both readiness and liveness probe will start checking the pod (after waiting for first 300 seconds).

Should the initialDelaySeconds of livenessProbe be always greated than that of readinessProbe? Reason being, if liveness checks fails before pod is ready, it will restart it and will get stuck in a loop.

What happens when both readiness probe and liveness probe are successful but because of some database downtime, readiness probe starts failing. And the whole webserver is not responding i.e. both endpoints readiness and liveness become unavailable. In this case, I think it will again be stuck in crashing loop, unless the database downtime is over.



First, you need to understand how Kubernetes makes use of the probes:

Liveness probes determine when to restart a container.
Readiness probes determine when a container is ready to start accepting traffic.

For scenarios that require Kubernetes to restart the pod to fix the issues, just make the liveness probe fail.
For scenarios that restarting the pod does not fix the issues, like your example of database downtime, then just make the readiness probe fail, and Kubernetes will just exclude that specific pod from traffic routing without restarting it.
To answer your questions:

Should the initialDelaySeconds of livenessProbe be always greated than that of readinessProbe?

Logically, your application needs to be live first before it is ready to accept traffics so it would make sense to have initialDelaySeconds of livenessProbe to be less or equal than initialDelaySeconds of readinessProbe

What happens when both readiness probe and liveness probe are successful but because of some database downtime, readiness probe starts failing.

Your liveness and readiness probes should be designed in a way that failures of external dependencies only fail the readiness probe but not the liveness probe. That way, your pod is not restarted in loop cycles until the database is up again. Keep in mind that when a pod goes into CrashLoopBackoff status, the cluster will increase the delay to wait before restarting the pod, so there will a delay when the database is up yet the pod is not restarted yet due to the increased timeout and thus losing your uptime SLA unnecessarily.

Also see Liveness, Readiness, and Startup Probes and associated pages in the Kubernetes documentation.  As that page notes, there are three different kinds of probes:

Startup probes check to see if the container is started up the first time; no other probes run until they pass.
Liveness probes check to see if the container process is actually running; they do not run until the startup probe (if any) passes; if it fails, Kubernetes restarts the container.
Readiness probes check to see if the process successfully handles traffic; they do not run until the startup probe (if any) passes; if it fails, the Pod is removed from the associated Service until it succeeds again.

Liveness and readiness probes are related, but one does not explicitly depend on the other.  If the liveness probe fails then the Pod will get restarted, but there's not a specific requirement that a liveness probe succeed before a readiness probe can be tried.

Should the initialDelaySeconds of livenessProbe be always greated than that of readinessProbe?

It doesn't matter.  The argument you make in the question is reasonable, that if the Pod will outright fail then you shouldn't attach it to the Service at all.  initialDelaySeconds: should probably be something like 15 seconds at the most, though; you might need to redesign your application startup if it's really taking 5 minutes for the service to be able to handle requests.

...because of some database downtime, readiness probe starts failing.

I'd redesign your probes in this case.  If the database fails, then all of the associated Pods will fail.  There's no point in restarting the container because the database is still down, so the liveness probe shouldn't fail.  You could have the readiness probe fail, but it will fail for all of the Pods, and so the Service won't have anything attached to it.  You'll get the same HTTP 503 error either way but from the Service rather than the individual Pods, and when the database recovers, you'll need to wait a little longer for the service to become available again.
